# Fix redirect url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 2.3.8.

I have this in my shop controller.

```
  def destroy
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    @shop.destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully deleted ' + @shop.shop_type.singularize + '.'
    redirect_to shops_path(@shop.shop_type)
  end
```

Whenever I delete the shop, I want it to be redirected to the proper `shop_type`. It redirects me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/shops.places
```

instead of the correct URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/shops?type=places
```

What can I do to redirect to the proper URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following. I've changed the redirect_to line

```
def destroy
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @shop.destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Successfully deleted ' + @shop.shop_type.singularize + '.'
  redirect_to shops_path(:type => @shop.shop_type)
end
```